# Objects are not valid as a React child - If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'


/** Custom Hook */
import { useFetchQestion } from '../hooks/FetchQuestions.js'
import { updateResult } from '../hooks/setResult.js'


export default function Questions({ onChecked }) {

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(undefined)
    const { trace } = useSelector(state => state.questions);
    const result = useSelector(state => state.result.result);
    const [{ isLoading, serverError}] = useFetchQestion() 

    const questions = useSelector(state => state.questions.queue[state.questions.trace])
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(updateResult({ trace, checked}))
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [checked]) 
    
    function onSelect(i){
        onChecked(i)
        setChecked(i)
        dispatch(updateResult({ trace, checked}))
    }


    if(isLoading) return <h3 className='text-light'>Loading</h3>
    if(serverError) return <h3 className='text-light'>{serverError || "Unknown Error"}</h3>

  return (
    <div className='questions'>
        <h2 className='text-light'>{questions?.question}</h2>

        <ul key={questions?.id}>
            {
                questions?.options.map((q, i) => (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            value={false}
                            name="options"
                            id={`q${i}-options`}
                            onChange={() => onSelect(i)}
                        />

                        <label className='text-primary' htmlFor={`q${i}-option`}>{q}</label>
                        <div className={`check ${result[trace] === i ? 'checked' : ''}`}></div>
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is my Questions.js file and I am trying to access an array from data.js but it keeps giving me the error saying -

"If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

not sure what the problem is.
I am also using map but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This issue comes when the React tries to render an `Object` (_JSON object_: `{ }`). What are the example values of `questions` (specifically `questions?.question` and `questions.options`), and `serverError `?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to render `q` in `<label className='text-primary' htmlFor={`q${i}-option`}>{q}</label>`. What is the format of `q`?